# CATiledLayer: Configure scale for next level of detail

Tags: ios, core-animation, mkmapview, catiledlayer

`CATiledLayer` create for showing images with tiles. So if `tileSize` is more then current place for it, `CATiledLayer` show next level of detail. How can i control this process and get behavior as in MKTiledLayer?

**UPDATE**
Problem are that  `-drawLayer:inContext:` calls with next level of details. How can i prevent this calls?

Answer (score 0):

Implement `CALayer`'s `-drawLayer:inContext:` method, as this will be called whenever it needs more rendering data:

> As more data is required by the renderer, the layer's
>   drawLayer:inContext: method is called on one or more background
>   threads to supply the drawing operations to fill in one tile of data.
>   The clip bounds and CTM of the drawing context can be used to
>   determine the bounds and resolution of the tile being requested.

(From [`CALayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)'s class reference.)